# Map of immutable list is only updating the last index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, immutability, immutable.js

I have this declaration:

```
  const players = immutable.fromJS({
    enabled: true,
    contract,
  })
```

and I have a checkbox that basically toggles the `enabled` to `true/false`.

I also have 'Enabled All' checkbox that I'm doing right now:

```
playerKeys && playerKeys.map((playerKey, i) => {
          players.set(playerKey, players.get(playerKey).set('enabled', e.target.checked))
        })
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with this function but it only changes the last index of list.

Is there a way to fix my 'Enabled All' checkbox so it will update all the items on my list?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a value while setting a value, you probably just missed a ")"

players.set(**playerKey, players.get(playerKey).*set*('enabled', e.target.checked)**)

This instruction **players.get(playerKey).*set*('enabled', e.target.checked)** returns nothing, so you are setting nothing to the parent function players.set

[EDIT]

```
playerKeys && playerKeys.map((playerKey, i) => {
    players.get(playerKey).set('enabled', e.target.checked)
})
```

Comment: just the same even I use forEach

Comment: @ajbee Updated the answer. If e.target.checked is triggered, just set the value of your event.target to the list. no need to get the value from players since the value is absolute and you want to apply it to all the players

Answer (score 0):

I had almost similar experience, but in my case nothing was not updating until I realised: updating immutable Map or List returns another immutable Map or List, doesn't modify original List or Map. Obviously that's what immutable means.

So to begin with you should make the `players` variable and then

```js
playerKeys && playerKeys.map((playerKey, i) => {
    players = players.get(playerKey).set('enabled', e.target.checked)
})
```

this should ideally work!